# ssh raspberrypi.local works but ping does not work

Tags: networking, ssh, ping

```
ping raspberrypi.local
ping: cannot resolve raspberrypi.local: Unknown host
```

But `ssh pi@raspberrypi.local` works.

I can ping by ip address.

Comment: That is indeed strange. If `ping` cannot resolve the hostname, neither should `ssh` be able to do that. Does `nslookup raspberrypi.local` give the right IP address?

Comment: You have omitted details crucial to an informed answer. Please edit your question to add details, or you are unlikely to get a helpful answer. ALSO: Have you made ***any*** modifications to `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` - or any network-related files in `/etc`?